# How to get a name value from a foreign key of a Json object

Tags: python, django, angularjs

I have used Django in one of my project.I have also used angularjs. In mention I am very new in Django and Angularjs.Now This is one of my view where i have retrieving data from one of my model namely **SubscribePlan**.

```
def subscribed(request):
    from django.core import serializers
    subscribedplan = SubscribePlan.objects.filter(user = request.user)
    subscribing = serializers.serialize('json',subscribedplan)

    return HttpResponse(subscribing)
```

and the models.py for the **SubscribePlan** is

```
class SubscribePlan(models.Model):
    plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan)
    expiriary_date = models.DateTimeField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

here you can see that the **plan** is a foreign key.Now i have used the anuglarjs in my template to get data to show the **name** of the **plan** of the associated user using the above given view **subscribed**.i have used angularjs in this tempalate like this..

```
{% extends 'userena/base_userena.html' %}

{% load i18n %}
{% load url from future %}

{% block title %}{% blocktrans with profile.user.username as username %}{{ username }}'s profile.{% endblocktrans %}{% endblock %}
{% block content_title %}<h2>{{ profile.user.username }} {% if profile.user.get_full_name %} ({{ profile.user.get_full_name }}){% endif %}</h2>{% endblock %}

{% block content %}


   <div class="panel-body">

     <h4 ng-controller='SubscribedPlanCtrl'>Subscribe Plan: <span style = "color:red">{[{subscribedplan.0.plan}]}</span></h4>

   </div>

{%block extrajs%}
    <script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('shutter',[]);
app.config(function($httpProvider){
//$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = {% csrf_token %};
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
});
app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
$interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
});   




app.controller('SubscribedPlanCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){

  $http.get('/showphoto/subscribing/').success(function(subdata){

    $scope.subscribedplan = subdata;

   }).error(function(subdata,status){
        $scope.datas = subdata || "Request Fail";
        $scope.status = status;
        console.log(status);


});
}]);
 </script>
{%endblock%}            
{% endblock %}
```

here in the template you can see that i have used **{[{subscribedplan.0.plan}]}** to show the name of the **plan**.

But the problem is, instead of showing the name of the **plan** ,its showing the **id** of the  **plan**.Remember that the **plan** is a foreign key.Now how can i show name of **plan**.

Comment: This isn't in any way a question about Angular, but about Django serialization.

Comment: Then please edit the name of the question.

Comment: You can use Django's natural keys or serialize the object yourself

Comment: can you please explain it as a answer,cause i have already serialized the object,so not understaning that the way you suggesting to serialize the object,so if it works well then i will accept it @arocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Django's [natural keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/serialization/#natural-keys) or construct the JSON object yourself. The latter is fine, in this case, since it is a small model and you don't need to deserialize it. An example code (untested):

```
from json import json

def subscribed(request):
    subscribedplan = SubscribePlan.objects.filter(user=request.user)[0]
    json_obj = [{"plan": subscribedplan.plan.name }, ]

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(json_obj))
```

Would recommend a more complete package like django-angular for better integration.